# Actions on lightning datatable go out of screen for LWC

Tags: lightning-datatable

I have an LWC which uses datatable actions. I have inserted actions at the start of row. When I click on it, it opens to the left and goes out of the screen. I did not insert actions to the end of the row as row is long and it would need horizontal scrolling to access it. Is there any way to make actions open to the right?

[image: screenshot]

```js
const columns = [
    {
        type: 'action',
        typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions },
    },
    { label: 'Contact',initialWidth: 190, fieldName: 'Contact_Name', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Type',initialWidth: 100, fieldName: 'Role', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Address',initialWidth: 310, fieldName: 'Address_custom', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Phone',initialWidth: 190, fieldName: 'Phone_Primary__c', type: 'phone' },
    { label: 'IsPrimary',initialWidth: 100,fieldName: 'Primary_Account__c', type: 'boolean' },
    { label: 'Notes',initialWidth: 100,fieldName: 'NotesNotEmpty__c', type: 'text' },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer if you're in LWC, and not Aura:

```
{ 
   type: 'action', 
   typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions, 
                     menuAlignment: 'left' } 
}
```

But first try **menuAlignment: 'auto'**, works wonders, as mentioned by @BritishBoyinDC

Comment: hit this same issue yesterday - I found auto rather than left had a better outcome so I would also try that if left doesn't give you what you need

Answer (score 3):

You should add an attribute to the action column you wish to fix -  
eg.
 `"cellAttributes: { menu-alignment:"left" }"`

you will find the right attribute to add based on the element you are using inside the cell  - thats the documentation :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation